# bash : Illegal number

Tags: bash, shell

When I run this bash script :

```
if [ [$EUID -ne 0] ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2 
   exit 1
else 

printf " whathever "

exit 0 
fi
```

I have this error :

```
./myScript: 15: [: Illegal number: [
```

Do you see any problem ?

Comment: It seems its trying to compare `[$EUID` against `0]` instead of `$EUID` against `0`

Comment: Fun fact : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_number

Answer (score 11):

You have syntax error in your if condition, use this if condition:

```
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ];
```

OR using `[[` and `]]`

```
if [[ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]];
```

Comment: Whats the difference between using `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` ?

Comment: `[` is actually an external program as `/bin/[` and `[[ ]]` are new BASH constructs to do test evaluation.

Comment: Using the first, I have this error : [: Illegal number:
Using the second, I have this error : [[: not found

Comment: Okay, so I suppose `$EUID` is something you fetched using `pidof` right? It so happens `pidof` will return an empty string if it fails to find the process, not 0. Thats why you are having this error. Try `if [ "$EUID" == "" ];` instead.

Comment: @anubhava: `[` is both an external program (also known as `test`) *and* a bash built-in command. If you're seeing `[[: not found`, you're probably not using bash. Is the first line of your script `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, or something else?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes agreed `[` is both an external program (also known as test) and a bash built-in command.

Comment: @4m1nh4j1: Your question was tagged as `BASH` that's why I suggested use of `[[ ]]`

Comment: @4m1nh4j1: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Answer (score 4):

> You have syntax error in your if condition, use this if condition:
>
> ```
> if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ];
> ```
>
> OR using `[[` and `]]`
>
> ```
> if [[ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]];
> ```

If you use the KSH88+/Bash 3+ internal instruction `[[`, it's not necessary to use doubles quotes around the variables operands :

```
[ ~/test]$ [[ $var2 = "string with spaces" ]] && echo "OK" || echo "KO" 
OK
```

Instead of the external command `test` or his fork `[` :

```
[ ~/test]$ [ $var2 = "string with spaces" ] && echo "OK" || echo "KO" 
bash: [: too many arguments
KO 
[ ~/test]$ [ "$var2" = "string with spaces" ] && echo "OK" || echo "KO" 
OK
```

Of course, you also have to choose the operators according to the type of operands :

```
[ ~/test]$ var1="01" 
[ ~/test]$ [ "$var1" = "1" ] && echo "OK" || echo "KO" 
KO 
[ ~/test]$ [ "$var1" -eq "1" ] && echo "OK" || echo "KO" 
OK
```

Answer (score 4):

two suggestions apart from what everyone else has pointed out already.

1. rather than doing `else [bunch of code because we are root] fi`, just replace the `else` with `fi`.  once you've tested for the failure condition you are concerned about and taken appropriate action, no need to continue to be within the body of the conditional.
2. `$EUID` is a bashism, if you would like to make this portable to shells such as ksh, replacing it with:

> `if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then echo "ur not root bro"; exit 1; fi`

would be a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
sudo bash shell_script.sh
```

instead of

```
sudo sh shell_script.sh
```

solved in my case.

Comment: definitely not, because the OP used `[ [$EUID -ne 0] ]` and not `[[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]`

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]
```

and run your script with `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`.

If executing from an `.sh` file, make sure to add the shebang `#!/bin/bash`.

Since you mentioned bash - so make sure you're using the right shell.

At least this solved my problem. Hope it helped.

Comment: the OP used `[ [$EUID -ne 0] ]` and not `[[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]` so using bash won't help. The syntax is definitely wrong

Comment: op mentioned bash so I assume making sure we're using the right shell (in the first place) will help.