# Array elements in Bash scripts

Tags: bash, if-statement

How can I use an if statement such as this to compare the element value to a variable.
For example i'm going through an array of numbers, and checking the minimum.  I'm having syntax problems.

```
for ((j=0;j<$i;j++)); do
if [ "$array[$j]" -gt $min ]; then
        min=${array[$j]}
fi
done
echo The minimum number is $min
```

Comment: Easier to loop over an array with `for el in "${array[i]}"`.

Comment: Or, in zsh, `echo ${${(n)ary}[1]}`.

Comment: @Kevin typo spotted: `for el in "${array[@]}"` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement lacks `then` clause:

```
if [ "$array[$j]" -gt $min ]; then
    min=${array[$j]}
fi
```

Also, in the true spirit of UNIX tools, consider something more elegant:

```
min_elem=$(echo ${array[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | head -1)
```

Comment: Error: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
I implemented this syntax and still does not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: What about `for`? You need `;do` as well

Comment: pretty clever way to get a minimum element.  Although, I'm trying to get used to the loops and if statement comparisons.  I care more about learning the syntax of those.  Although, soon enough I plan to get more elegant :)

Comment: Updated script at the top, and it's still not working.  What do you think is incorrect?

Comment: "$array[$j]" is not correct, but it's not a syntax error. You need the curly braces for it to work.

Comment: Why do you need {}?  New to bash :(.  Sry for newbness.  I normally do C# and c++

Comment: @camdixon: because you do :). That's the way bash syntax works. Without the {}, it's two variable expansions, first $array and then $j, together in a string with []. If `array` is an array, then `$array` is the same as `${array[0]}`. Why? Because that's the way it was written.

Comment: I personally don't find your last subshell-pipe-pipe-pipe elegant at all! it's awful. At least you could have written `read min_element < <(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | sort -n)` to get rid of two unneeded external tools and two unneeded pipes! Oh dear... you thought your thing was _elegant_...

Answer (score 0):

Several comments:

- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570) to know when and how to protect your variables ;
- `-gt` isn't the desired operator for getting the min

Here's a simple corrected example (just Bash without other commands) :

```
#!/bin/bash

array=("1" "0" "2")
length="${#array[@]}"
min="${array[0]}"

for (( i=1 ; i < "$length"; i++)); do
    [[ ${array[$i]} -le $min ]] && min="${array[$i]}"
done

echo "The minimum number is $min"
```

EDIT : Test performed after the comment of gniourf_gniourf (see the comments)

```
[ ~]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

array=("1" "0" "2")
m=${array[0]}; for i in "${array[@]:1}"; do ((i<m)) && m=$i; done
echo "The minimum number is $m"
[ ~]$ ./test.sh 
The minimum number is 0
[ ~]$ vi test.sh
[ ~]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

array=("1" "0" "2")
m="${array[0]}"; for i in "${array[@]:1}"; do [[ $i -le $m ]] && m="$i"; done
echo "The minimum number is $m"
[ ~]$ ./test.sh 
The minimum number is 0
[ ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't totally work with my laptop. I edited my post for better reading results. With a slight modification it works well.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the previous (I deleted it). Please read: `m=${array[0]}; for i in "${array[@]:1}"; do ((i<m)) && m=$i; done` and I edited your post to fix it!