# Basic Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have written a script to find out the current processes running on the system with their project name.But after executing script i m getting too many line with status code = 0 as output.Can anyone please help me on this i am new to scripting.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 dsjob -lprojects >ProjectName.txt   #Fetching the datastage project name running on the             server                  

 ps -ef | grep DSD.RUN | cut -d" " -f21 > Currentjoblog.txt  #this will contains the     current running job on the server

 for i in $(< ProjectName.txt);do
 dsjob -ljobs $i > $i.txt 
 for j in $(< $i.txt);do
 cat $Currentjoblog.txt | while read LINE
 do
 if [ x$j == x$LINE ] ;then
  echo "$i-------$LINE"
 fi
 done <"$CurrentJoblog.txt"
 done
 done
```

Comment: Testing strings using the idiom `x$var = xstring` is only required in very old shells which will very likely not recognize the validity of `==` (they generally run on systems on which the `test` (aka `[`) command requires `=`).

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to use temporary files :

```
dsjob -lprojects|while read l1; do
     dsjob -ljobs $l1|while read l2; do
         # you could use $l2 here
         # ...
     done
done
```

Here is a reminder on how to read a command output or file content with a loop in Bash : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361#19607361)

Otherwise :

> ```
> cat $Currentjoblog.txt | while read LINE
> do
>     # ...
> done <"$CurrentJoblog.txt"
> ```

This syntax is wrong. Either you read the output of the `cat`, or you read the file content by redirection but not both (see my previous link for the right syntax).

Otherwise :

> ```
> if [ x$j == x$LINE ] ;then
>     # ...
> fi
> ```

You have to protect your variables with doubles quotes, when you use the command `test` or `[` syntaxe instead of `[[`. I also think that the `x` which foregoing the operands are errors ;)

Here is a reminder about the necessity (or not) to protect your variables with double quotes : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use [**pgrep**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) which *"looks up or signals processes based on name and other"*

example:

```
$> pgrep $(dsjob -lprojects)
```