# Bash Script if elif elif not working

Tags: linux, bash

So I am trying to do an if else if else statement in a bash script. As of now when I run this script I get the following error message "./groupJobs.sh: line 76: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./groupJobs.sh: line 76:`elif [ $jobsize -lt $2 ]; then'"

I have looked online at multiple examples and cannot see any difference in what I have done and what others say works.

Any help would be appreciated. 
(line 76 is the last elif statement)

```
if [ $filesize -ge $2 ]; then
#goes this way if file is to big to put in a job with anyother files
$filename >> $jobname$jobnumber;

elif [ $jobsize -ge $2 ]; then
#job is done being created

elif [ $jobsize -lt $2 ]; then
#add file to job and move on to next file check

fi
```

Comment: the error msg looks like there might not be a space between `elif` and `[`. Looks ok in your code abve. I would move the `;` chars so there is a space separating them from `]`, but it may not be necessary. AND it never hurts to wrapp all variables in dbl-quotes, ie. `"$filename" >> "$jobname$jobnumber"`.  Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to the bash tag! Check out the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for good tips on what to do before asking. In this case, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) will helpfully pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `elif` statements need an actual statement. Put something like `echo "job creation done"` and `echo "add file to job"` in those statements (or whatever else you want) for the time being...

```
if [ $filesize -ge $2 ]; then
#goes this way if file is to big to put in a job with anyother files
$filename >> $jobname$jobnumber;

elif [ $jobsize -ge $2 ]; then
#job is done being created
echo "whatever you want"
#the above line just has to be some sort of actual statement

elif [ $jobsize -lt $2 ]; then
#add file to job and move on to next file check
echo "whatever you want"
#the above line just has to be some sort of actual statement
fi
```

Comment: You can use the null command `:` as a statement. This way, you don't have to even echo anything out.

Comment: @NicolasEdwards yup, doesn't matter what you put in there, just need something other than a comment

Comment: You should use `[[` instead of `[` or `test` in bash. Otherwise, you should protect your variable with doubles quotes. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570

Answer (score 4):

The body of an `elif` block cannot be empty (a comment doesn't count). If you just need to stub out the body, use the `:` function.

```
if [ $filesize -ge $2 ]; then
#goes this way if file is to big to put in a job with anyother files
$filename >> $jobname$jobnumber;

elif [ $jobsize -ge $2 ]; then
#job is done being created
:

elif [ $jobsize -lt $2 ]; then
#add file to job and move on to next file check
:

fi
```

Comment: You should use `[[` rather than `[` or `test` in bash. Otherwise, you should protect your variable with doubles quotes. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570

Answer (score 1):

Bash requires a command (e.g. `echo`) in the if/elif blocks. Comments do not count.