# Program that removes all files accept txt files in folder

Tags: bash, unix

Takes 2 arguments , source & destination and removes all files except txt.
.Im just learning bash so not used/aware of the different functions etc...

```
mkdir $2
cp -R $1/* $2

for file in $1/*;do #all files in testInput
   if [ -d "$file" ] #if its a file then look at the contents of it
   then
      for inDir in $file/*; do
         if [ -d "$inDir" ]
         then
            for line in $inDir ; do
               if [ line != *.txt ]
               then
                  rm line

               fi
            done
          fi
       done

    else
       for files in file; do
          if [ files != *.txt ]
          then
             rm files
          fi
       done

    fi     
done
```

source is a folder which contains the 3 folders and some of these subfolder contain a subfolder and files

Comment: OK, and what is the question?

Comment: You are missing several `$`s before variable names.

Comment: Everybody seems to have their assignments due on Monday.

Comment: Can't you just use `find` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `find` to do that kind of task. Here is an example :

```
find "$dir" -type f ! -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} \;
```

Otherwise :

> ```
> if [ line != *.txt ]
> # ...
> if [ files != *.txt ]
> ```

You're missing the `$` before the variable name and the test is incorrect. You could try something like this instead :

```
[[ $line =~ \.txt$ ]] || rm line
```

Moreover :

> ```
> for files in file; do
> ```

You're missing the character `$` before the variable name and you should use something like this instead :

```
for files in "$file"/*; do
```

Finally, you don't protect your variables properly. Read this : [bash : Illegal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570)

Comment: +1 for `=~`. Totally unused thoses days while it should. Many regex problems can be solved this way without the use of `grep` etc

Comment: The `=~` operator is only available in bash >= 3. But bash >= 3 is available on all Linux versions and Mac OS X. So I also like to use this operator instead of an external program like `grep` ;)

Comment: So how will i implement my function with find?

Answer (score 1):

Takes all files in directory $1 except *.txt files and moves them to directory $2.

```
find "$1" -type f ! -name "*.txt" -exec mv -v "{}" "$2" \;
```

As always, be careful with this...

**edit** added quotes around variables

**edit2** quoted file name placeholder, added debug output to mv

Comment: Maybe add some quotes around the variables to be on the safe side.

Comment: The `{}` should also be quoted. And for some feedback, either add `-print` to `find` or `-v` to `mv`.