# Check file existence every 30 seconds

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, while-loop, terminal

Why doesn't this work? I need to check the existence of a file every 30 seconds.

```
STATUS=0
FILENAME="helloworld.file"
while [ $STATUS -eq "0" ] do
if [ -f $FILENAME ];
    then STATUS=1;
else
    sleep 30s;
fi

done
```

Comment: Line 3 you forgot a semi colon: `while [ $STATUS -eq "0" ]; do`

Comment: @Michal Kordas if you're going to go around fixing typos please fix everything in the post while you're at it. This doesn't necessarily apply to this edit specifically but several of your latest suggested edits have missed significant problems in the post.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, sure I will do more thorough reviews

Comment: @Michal cheers, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, let's ask [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)!

```
In file line 3:
while [ $STATUS -eq "0" ] do
                          ^-- SC1010: Use semicolon or linefeed before 'do' (or quote to make it literal).
```

Ok, then let's do that:

```
STATUS=0
FILENAME="helloworld.file"
while [ $STATUS -eq "0" ]
do
if [ -f $FILENAME ];
    then STATUS=1;
else
    sleep 30s;
fi

done
```

Comment: `shellcheck`: that's cool! Maybe that should be made a requirement before posting questions to SO. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `;` ==>

```
while [ "$STATUS" -eq "0" ]; do
if [ -f "$FILENAME" ]; then 
    STATUS=1
else
    sleep 30
fi
```

Or :

```
while [ "$STATUS" -eq "0" ] 
do
    if [ -f "$FILENAME" ]
    then 
        STATUS=1
    else
        sleep 30
    fi
done
```

Moreover, do not forget to protect your variables with doubles quotes or favoring the syntax `[[`.

[Here is a reminder about the necessity (or not) to protect your variables with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570).

You could also simplify your code :

```
while true; do
    [[ -f $FILENAME ]] && break
    sleep 30
done
```