# whats the best practice for conditionals in bash when checking multiple statements?

Tags: bash

Given your trying to check that a variable is not empty and not some other value as in the following code:

```
if [ ! -z "$foo" ] && [[ ${foo} != "bar" ]]; then
```

what is the best practice for accomplishing this. I've seen bash conditionals written several ways including the following...

```
if [[ ! -z "$foo" && ${foo} != "bar" ]]; then
```

I understand there is a difference when using the single brackets and the double, I'm more concerned with when to put the `&&` or `||` inside the brackets or out.

Comment: You only need one conditional: if `foo` is empty, it's not going to equal `bar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `&&`/`||` inside brackets for `[[ ]]`. Outside is also accepted.

Put `&&`/`||` outside brackets for `[ ]`. Inside is NOT allowed.

This is due to the fact that `&&` binds normal commands together based on return value, e.g.

```
wget file && echo "Success"
```

`[`, despite its funny name, is a regular command and obeys the same rules as e.g. `wget` or `echo`.

`[ foo || bar ]` is two commands, `[ foo` and `bar ]`, neither of which are valid.

`[[ .. ]]` on the other hand is not a normal command but special shell syntax. `[[ foo || bar ]]` is a single command, and interpretted accordingly.

Comment: `[` is a builtin in Bash.

Comment: Yes it is, but that's an implementation optimization.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `[[` is a builtin, `[` is an alias for the program `test`.

Comment: @Swiss `[`/`test` is also a standalone program, one of several that `bash` implements as built-in commands (along with `kill`, `echo`, `printf`, and others) for efficiency.

Comment: @Swiss `[[` is a keyword and `[` is a builtin. Please check with `type [[` and `type [` in bash.

Comment: @thatotherguy not only an implementation optimization. `builtin [` has more options that `command [` (on my system).

Comment: btw, I don't want to argue whether builtin/command, we all know what what is. Just that it's not exactly clear in your answer (and the question is tagged bash): reading it without knowing would confort me into thinking that `[` is really the command `/usr/bin/[`.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the previous answers :

```
if [[ ! -z $foo && $foo != "bar" ]]; then ...
# [[ will execute the two conditions with "and" operator in a single instruction
```

Is equivalent of :

```
if [[ ! -z $foo -a $foo != "bar" ]]; then ...
# [[ will execute the two conditions with "and" operator in a single instruction
```

But not equivalent of :

```
if [[ ! -z $foo ]] && [[ $foo != "bar" ]]; then ...
# second [[ will be executed if the first success ($? = 0)
```

`-a` (and) and `-o` (or) will work with `test` and `[`.

See `man test` to get more details ;)

Otherwise, no need to protect your variables by doubles quotes with `[[` and no need to use delimiters (`${}`) in this case.

[Here is a reminder about the necessity (or not) to protect your variables with double quotes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570).