# Script for CentOS to restart MySQL service whenever it is stopped

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I want to write a script for restart MySQL service whenever it is in stopped status.
I don't know how to write the IF statement on this script.

Comment: Then go check the documentation. Once you've done that and if you're still stuck, [edit] your question with the code that's not working.

Comment: google "if example in shell script"

Answer (score 2):

@vastlysuperiorman

> ```
> if [ ! $(ps aux | grep mysql) ]
> then
>    service mysql restart
> fi
> ```

First, don't forget to protect your operand. See this reminder : [bash : Illegal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570)

Then, you could simplify by :

```
[[ $(ps -ef | grep [m]ysql) ]] || service mysql restart
```

(I prefere to use `ps -ef` because it's more POSIX compliant even if I always use `[[` instead of `test` or `[` in Bash).

Finaly, it's better to check the status with `service mysql status`. You could try something like instead :

```
[[ $(service mysql status) =~ running ]] || service mysql restart
```

@user33398

You could try to use this test in a loop or with `watch` command for example. Or you could use more smart tools like `cron` or `jenkins` or `nagios` to do that.

Comment: It says too much argument when i run the script.

Comment: @user33398 Thank you to copy/paste the command that fails, I am not psychic ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann, `ps aux | grep mysql` will always return true. Instead what you need is `ps aux | grep [m]ysql`. Run both the commands and you will find the difference.

Comment: Dear IDRISS NEUMAN! if [ ! $(ps aux | grep mysql) ] 
this one doesnot work and even if MySQL be stopped it shows MYSQL is there since GREP MYSQL is a process that contains MySQL within it.

Dear SLAYEDBYLUCIFER ,[m]ysql is the correct one. i 'm going to check it

Comment: @user33398 I said that is better to check the status of mysql with `[[ $(service mysql status) =~ running ]] || service mysql restart` instead ;) (it always works).

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Try to run `echo "$(ps aux|grep mysql)"` intead of `ps aux|grep mysql` and you'll find the difference ;) . And `[[ string ]]` doesn't check if the result is true but if it's not empty (it's an equivalent of `-n` option of `test`). But I like your tip so I upvote :)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann, you are mistaken. Run these two commands and you will notice the difference: `if [[ $(ps -ef | grep mysql) ]] ; then echo hello; fi` **AND** `if [[ $(ps -ef | grep [m]ysql) ]] ; then echo hello; fi`. The 1st command will **ALWAYS** print `hello` because the if condition turns true always. Besides, waht you have mentioned in the comment above also follows what I am explaining here.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I've edited my answer, you can see the result of these commands in my OS ;)

Comment: @slayedbylucifer You're right. I've tried on a second OS (mac OS with bash) and the process that corresponds of the `grep` command is returned in my `echo "$(ps-ef | grep mysql)"`. Do you know how to explain that difference of behavior ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Shell are you on? What is the shell version? Mine is `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`. I tried it on RHEL and Ubuntu and it acted the way I mentioned above. So, My responses were only with respect to BASH.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer The first test was done on an old Ubuntu server with GNU/bash 3.2.39. The second (which behaves as you describe) on Mac OS with GNU/bash 4.2.45.

Comment: Hmmm.. I dont have a 3.2.39 at my disposal. May be, that what causing  different behaviour. Anyway, A good practice is to upgrade the bash version (OR Ubuntu in a broader perspective). Also please update your answer accordingly as OP also probably running 4.2.25 version of BASH as he has mentioned in one the comments that the `ps ...` command always returns true.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Anyway, to be compatible between the different versions of Bash, it's better to do as you done ... (but for this case I still prefer to use `service mysql status` as in my answer. It still works in all cases). So I've corrected my post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No sense re-inventing the wheel. There are great software solutions out there that can do this for you. Monit is a good open source example.

If you do opt to write a script, a simple solution could be to do something like the following:

```
if [ ! $(ps aux | grep mysql) ]
then
    service mysql restart
fi
```

Comment: `ps aux | grep mysql` will always return true. Instead what you need is `ps aux | grep [m]ysql`. Run both the commands and you will find the difference.

Comment: This is true. The grep would show up in the list. I'm going to have to advocate Idriss Neuman's answer on this one. He's right that `[[ $(service mysql status) =~ running ]] || service mysql restart` is probably the most effective solution (I'm new so I can't upvote).