# ip proxy testing using wget not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, proxy, grep, wget

I am testing some IP:Port proxy by downloading something to see if some of these proxy valid or not. My working script is

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> for pro in $(cat testing.txt);do
>
> wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=$pro --tries=1 --timeout=15 http://something.com/download.zip
> if grep --quiet "200 OK"; then
>   echo $pro >> ok.txt
> else
>   echo $pro >>notok.txt
> fi
>
> done
> ```

Typical output on success by wget is

> ```
> --2014-06-08 10:45:31--  http://something.com/download.zip
> Connecting to 186.215.168.66:3128... connected.
> Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
> Length: 30688 (30K) [application/zip]
> Saving to: `download.zip'
>
> 100%[======================================>] 30,688      7.13K/s   in 4.2s
> ```

and output on failure is

> ```
> --2014-06-08 10:45:44--  http://something.com/download.zip
> Connecting to 200.68.9.92:8080... connected.
> Proxy request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
> Giving up.
> ```

now problem is , grep seems not working! It output all ip address in notok.txt file. Weather wget success or not it output all address in notok.txt . How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some corrections :

1) You should avoid to use `for i in $(cmd)`. You should read :

- this reminder on [how to read a command output or file content with a loop in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361?stw=2#19607361) ;
- this reminder about [the necessity (or not) to protect your variables with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570?stw=2#19598570).

2) `grep` must read a stream :

```
grep [options...] [pattern] file
command|grep [options...] [pattern]
grep [options...] [pattern] < <(command)
grep [options...] [pattern] <<< "some text"
```

3) No need to use `grep` in this case :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r pro; do
    out="$(wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=$pro --tries=1 --timeout=15 http://something.com/download.zip)"
    if [[ $out =~ "200 OK" ]]; then
        echo "$pro" >> ok.txt
    else
        echo "$pro" >> notok.txt
    fi
done < testing.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Bash script to check a list of proxies using wget

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

files="proxies_list.txt" #file with proxies to test in <ip>:<port> format

rm not_ok.txt
rm ok.txt

while read -r pro; do

    out=$(wget.exe -qO- --tries=1 --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate -e use_proxy=on -e https_proxy=$pro https://example.com)

    if [[ $out ]]; then
        echo "$pro" >> ok.txt
        echo "$pro  ----    OK"
    else
        echo "$pro" >> not_ok.txt
        echo "$pro  ----    NOT OK"
    fi
done < "$files"
```