# Bash - While Loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am having trouble with this while loop. Here is the error I am getting currently : [: : unary operator expected (on line 3)

Here is my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

while [ "$option" <= 3 ]; do
    echo "1) View 'HelloWorld' Text";
    echo "2) View 'MyName' Text";
    echo "3) View 'HappyFall' Text";
    echo "4) Exit\n";

    read -p "Please choose your option using numbers 1-4: " option;
        if [ "$option" == 1 ]
        then
            cat HelloWorld
        elif [ "$option" == 2 ]
        then
            cat MyName
        elif [ "$option" == 3 ]
        then
            cat HappyFall
        else
        echo "Exiting...";
        fi
done
```

Comment: I might need to mention that the error is in line 3 (while [ "$option" <= 3 ]; do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<=` is not a valid comparison in bash scripting, but `-le` (less than or equal) is.

There are two different types of comparison in scripting: those for strings, and those for numbers.

Stings typically use `==` or `!=` for equal or not equal.
Integers, however, use:

- `-eq` equal
- `-ne` not equal
- `-lt` less than
- `-le` less than or equal
- `-gt` greater than
- `-ge` greater than or equal

Here's a more comprehensive list:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29

Comment: When I change it to that I get another error: line 3: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: You've never declared `option` leading up to that point.  You're comparing "blank" to a number.  Define `option` to some default value like zero.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108548/error-in-two-scripts-unary-operator-expected-and-integer-expression-expected

Answer (score 3):

Error aside, this is a good use case for the `select` command:

```
options=(
    "View 'HelloWorld' Text"
    "View 'MyName' Text"
    "View 'HappyFall' Text"
    "Exit"
)
select option in "${options[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
        1) cat HelloWorld ;;
        2) cat MyName ;;
        3) cat HappyFall ;;
        *) break ;;
esac
done
```