# Unable to compare properly with if condition

Tags: bash, shell

I have written very simple logic below, but it is always complaining with my if condition.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

UBUNTU_VERSION=`lsb_release -r |  awk '{ print $2}'`
echo "UBUNTU_VERSION - $UBUNTU_VERSION"

if [[ "$UBUNTU_VERSION" -eq "14.04" ]];
then
        echo "Ubuntu 14.04"
else
        echo "Not Ubuntu 14.04"
fi
```

I get the error as :

```
./test.sh: 6: ./1.sh: [[: not found
```

If I change my code to:

```
if [ "$UBUNTU_VERSION" -eq "14.04" ];
```

or

```
if [ $UBUNTU_VERSION -eq "14.04" ];
```

I get error as :

```
./test.sh: 6: [: Illegal number: 14.04
```

I have already referred to this link to correct my code, but I am not able to fix this:

[bash : Illegal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number)

Comment: Use the '=' comparator. -eq is reserved for integer comparations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `#!/bin/bash` shebang at top for using bash syntax
- `eq` is for integer comparison only, use `=` or `==`
- Use `$(...)` for command substitution instead of old fashioned and buggy reverse ticks

**Modified Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

UBUNTU_VERSION=$(lsb_release -r |  awk '{ print $2}')
echo "UBUNTU_VERSION - $UBUNTU_VERSION"

if [[ $UBUNTU_VERSION == "14.04" ]];
then
        echo "Ubuntu 14.04"
else
        echo "Not Ubuntu 14.04"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`[[` is a bash-ism i.e. it is a `bash` keyword.

As you are interpreting the script as `sh`, which presumable is not `bash` and does not support `[[` (`dash`?), hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Note: -eq ,-ne ,-gt ,-lt  are used to compare integers. For string it won't work. You need to use == , !=

```
  UBUNTU_VERSION=`lsb_release -r |  awk '{ print $2}'`
   echo "UBUNTU_VERSION - $UBUNTU_VERSION"

if [ "$UBUNTU_VERSION" == "14.04" ];
then
        echo "Ubuntu 14.04"
else
        echo "Not Ubuntu 14.04"
fi
```