# How would I check if user exists in a bash script and re-ask for new user if user provided is present?

Tags: bash, security, scripting, automation

I'm a newbie to bash scripting, and I'm trying to make a script to setup some basic security on a ubuntu server. I have the following so far:

```
group="sudo"
read -p "Set new sudo user's name (Please try to avoid admin or administrator, some hosts have these reserved): " new_sudo_user_name
if [ -z "$(getent passwd $new_sudo_user_name)" ]; then
  echo "user does NOT exist."
else
  echo "user DOES exist."
fi

echo "Please enter the new password:"
read -s password1
echo "Please repeat the new password:"
read -s password2

if [ $password1 != $password2 ]; then
  echo "Passwords do not match"
  exit    
fi

sudo su -c "useradd $new_sudo_user_name -s /bin/bash -m -aG $group"
```

Essentially, what I'd like for it to do is to, upon checking if the username exists already to automatically re-ask for a new username if it is found to already exist. Is this possible? If so, what is best practice to accomplish this task?

Appreciate the help in advance :)

Comment: Just use a simple `while` loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Linux native way to know if a user already exists is to check in the `/etc/passwd` file like this:

```
if grep "${username}" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  # do something if the user exists
fi
```

Another way is to use `finger` command (which isn't always installed by default):

```
$ finger ineumann
Login: ineumann                 Name: Idriss Neumann
Directory: /home/ineumann               Shell: /bin/bash
On since Tue Jun 19 10:55 (CET) on tty2 from /dev/tty2
1 day 9 hours idle
No mail.
No Plan.
$ finger ineumanne
finger: ineumanne: no such user.
```

So you also could try something like:

```
[[ $(finger "${username}" 2>&1) =~ "no such user" ]] && echo "User not exists" || "User exists"
```

To answer the question about re-asking when a user exists, you could easily use a loop, `while` for example:

```
read -p "Username: " username
while grep "${username}" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  read -p "Try again: " username
done
# Create the user...
```

Or `until` for example:

```
read -p "Username: " username
until [[ $(finger "${username}" 2>&1) =~ "no such user" ]]; do
  read -p "Try again: " username
done
# Create the user...
```

Demo in terminal:

```
$ read -p "Username: " username; while grep "${username}" /etc/passwd >/dev/null 2>&1; do read -p "Try again: " username; done
Username: ineumann
Try again: ineumann
Try again: ineumann
Try again: Idonknow
$ read -p "Username: " username; until [[ $(finger "${username}" 2>&1) =~ "no such user" ]]; do read -p "Try again: " username; done
Username: ineumann
Try again: ineumann
Try again: ineumann
Try again: IdontKnow
```

By the way, here's a little advice on your script:

```
if [ $password1 != $password2 ]; then
  echo "Passwords do not match"
  exit    
fi
```

You should protect your operands `$password1` and `$password2` using either double quote or `[[` instead of `[`. See [this reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598570/2900196) to get more details.

Comment: Thanks for the protection reminder; will keep in mind :)
as for the actual solution, that's not what I was looking for, unfortunately. I already have a working means of checking if a user exists, I wanted to see what I should add in order to get the script to re-ask for a new username if the user is found to exist

Comment: @DavidRazdolski I completed my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do what I wanted it to :)

Comment: @DavidRazdolski I'm glad for you but please do not forget to mark this question as solved in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
while read -p "$prompt" user; getent passwd "$user" >/dev/null; do
    echo "user $user exists"
done
echo "proceeding with new user $user"
```