# If then else in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that checks whether `unzip` is installed on a RHEL server. If it is installed, the script should proceed, but if not, the following message should be displayed:

> Unzip package is not installed.

However, I am trying to be careful and consider that the versions may differ from server to server and I am not sure if I can use a wild card. Below is an example of what I am looking for.

```
UNZIP='rpm -qq unzip'
If [$UNZIP = unzip*] then 'RUN COMMAND' else echo "Unzip is not installed."
```

Comment: Terminate the if statement with fi. Put semicolon before then. If you could paste your bash --version it would help

Comment: In bash `[]` is an alias for the `test` command.  It isn't recognized unless you put a space after the `[` and before the `]`.  Also, you missed a semicolon after `]`.  All in all, it should look like `[ <condition> ]; then ...`.  And as @Attersson said, you need to terminate the if-else with a `fi`.

Comment: Seems like you need to read a tutorial on shell scripting, you have lots of basic syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
unzip_package="$(rpm -qq unzip)"
if [[ $unzip_package =~ ^unzip.*$ ]]; then
   # ... run command
else
   echo "Unzip is not installed."
fi
```

Here's a few comments on your code:

1) To run a command in subshell and catch the output in a variable, there's two syntax :

```
var="$(command)"
var=`command`
```

But not:

```
var='command'
```

2) You need space inside brackets in your test:

`[ -z "$unzip" ]`: `[` is an alias of the `test` command (or a builtin in bash with same behavior). You should also protect your operands with douple quotes when you use this syntax.

`[[ -z $unzip ]]`: available since KSH88 (in my memory) and allow more powerfull stuffs like testing regexp since bash 4+ with the `=~` operator.

You should see [this reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597962/bash-illegal-number/19598570#19598570) to get more details.

3) You miss a `fi` to close the `if` statement

4) Be careful with the case of statements: `if` and not `If`

5) You also miss multiples semicolons:

```
if <cmd1>; then <cmd2>; else <cmd3>; fi
```

Or:

```
if ...; then
  # do some stufs
else
  # ...
fi
```

Or:

```
if .... 
then
  # do some stufs
else
  # ...
fi
```

To conclude you really should learn a little bit more the basics of shell syntax and statements. Here's a really good [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for Bash.

Comment: To put the if statement on one line, you need semicolons in (perhaps) unexpected places: `if test-commands; then commands; else commands; fi`

Comment: Command substitution syntax of `$( ... )` is *not* specific to bash, it is allowed by POSIX:  "*Command substitution allows the output of a command to be substituted in place of the command name itself. Command substitution shall occur when the command is enclosed as follows:

$(command)

or (backquoted version):

\`command\`*"

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed my answer.